# prvalue of type std::nullptr_t

Tags: c++, rvalue

Section 4.10/1 N3797 says:

> A null pointer constant is an integer literal (2.14.2) with value zero
>   or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t.

I think `nullptr` is a `prvalue` of type `std::nullptr_t`. Would you get a bit more examples of such `prvalue`?

Answer (score 3):

As with any type, there are various ways to get a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`:

- cast from an appropriate expression: `static_cast<std::nullptr_t>(0)`
- temporary constructor call: `std::nullptr_t{}`
- call to a function returning `std::nullptr_t`: `std::nullptr_t f() { return {}; } f()`
- call to a lambda returning `std::nullptr_t`: `[]() -> std::nullptr_t { return {}; }()`
- a comma expression where the right hand side is a `std::nullptr_t` prvalue: `("hello", nullptr)`
- a conditional expression where one side has type `std::nullptr_t` and the other side is of a different value category or is a throw-expression: `false ? throw "oops" : nullptr`, `false ? std::move(nullptr) : nullptr`

Because `std::nullptr_t` does not participate in most operators, this is a reasonably exhaustative list; most other expressions with type `std::nullptr_t` will yield glvalues.